# In equation (8.37) of the Feynman lectures, it says $H_{ij}$ are derivatives with respect to $t_2$ of the coefficients $U_{ij}$. How do we show this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

In describing how states change with time Feynman first shows that, for small $\Delta t$, each coefficient $U_{ij}$ should differ from $\delta_{ij}$ by amounts proportional to $\Delta t$, like this,

$$U_{ij} =  \delta_{ij}  +  K_{ij} \Delta t .      \tag{8.36}$$

Then in equation (8.37) shown below he says to take out the $(-i/\hbar)$ out of the coefficient $K_{ij}$ to give this,

$$U_{ij}(t+\Delta t,t)  =  \delta_{ij} - (i/\hbar)H_{ij}(t)\Delta t. \tag{8.37}$$

He says the coefficients $H_{ij}$ (which is the Hamiltonian) are just the derivatives with respect to $t_2$ of the coefficients $U_{ij}(t_2,t_1)$, evaluated at $t_2=t_1=t$.

The derivative to use here I think is,

$$ \frac{\partial U_{ij}}{\partial t_2}(t_2,t_1) = \lim\limits_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{U_{ij}(t_2+\Delta t,t_1)-U_{ij}(t_2,t_1)}{\Delta t}.$$

However, I am not sure how this can be used to derive $H_{ij}$ and equation $(8.37)$ above. Does anyone know how to show this?

Comment: Perhaps you could put in context  what you are asking about to readers who do not have copies of the Feynman lectures?

Comment: Think back to your basic calculus - what's the definition of the derivative (hint: $\Delta t = h$ in the usual derivative limit notation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Feynman lectures volume 3 notes on chapter 8](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_08.html) are in the colloquial style of the lectures. In the relevant part of the text, the author is communicating that $U_{ij}(t_2,t_1)$ are quantities about which we don't have much intuition except that $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$ implies that $U_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$. As a matter of definition, $$U_{ij}(t_2+\Delta t,t_1) := \delta_{ij} + K_{ij}{\large |}_{(t_2,t_1)}\Delta t := \delta_{ij} - \frac{i}{\hbar} H_{ij}{\large |}_{(t_2,t_1)}\Delta t,$$
so that $H_{ij}{\large |}_{(t,t)} = - \frac{\hbar}{i}  \lim_{ \Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{ U_{ij}(t+\Delta t,t) - U_{ij}(t,t) }{\Delta t}.$

> The statement in the text 'the coefficients $H_{ij}$ (which is the Hamiltonian) are just the derivatives with respect to $t_2$ of the coefficients $U_{ij}(t_2,t_1)$, evaluated at $t_2=t_1=t$' should therefore be read after replacing the phrase 'just the derivatives' with the more accurate phrase 'just the derivatives multiplied by $- \frac{\hbar}{i}$'.